# Database design: Is it okay for a table to have half-related records?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a two hypothetical tables: `foo` and `bar`.

Sometimes, `foo` can be related to `bar`, so I make a `foo_bar` table to keep their ID's.

But sometimes `bar` is isolated on its own and has nothing to do with `foo`.

Is this frowned upon in the database world? Should I create a separate `foo_isolated` table for the `foo`'s that aren't related to `bar`'s?
 Why/why not?

**Update:**

I will try to be less abstract.

Say I have a `checkout` and `email` table. Sometimes I can send emails that are not related to a checkout, but often times a checkout is attached to a certain email.

Would it be okay for the `email` table to have records that have no matching record in the `checkout_email` table? In other words, the `email` table is basically a generic email table, and it just so happens to be used to store records that are related to a `checkout` via a `checkout_email` join table storing both ID's.

That is as close as I can get to a real example.

Comment: No, that should be fine

Comment: I can't work with abstract names like "foo" and "bar" - you haven't described *how* the two are related. Please reword your question using their actual names, or if it's too esoteric then please use a more relatable analogy.

Comment: @Dai Updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Specialization

One thing that is often done to accomplish this is called **specialization** This means that you will split your table into multiple tables that are related as follows: Let's look only at the right side of the image below. There are two entities 'SALARIED_EMPLOYEE' and 'HOURLY_EMPLOYEE' that are both related to 'EMPLOYEE'. This means that an employee can be paid per hour or per month (fixed salary) and depending on the type of payment, there will be a record in a different table for that user.

[image]

Specialization is done when there are (as in the image) multiple types of some entitiy (e.g. hourly/monthly payed employees) and those two have a lot of attributes in common (e.g. Name, Ssn, Birth_date, Address). We say that 'EMPLOYEE' is a superclass of 'SALARIED_EMPLOYEE' and 'HOURLY_EMPLOYEE'. Whenever an employee is added, there must also be a row added in one of the subclasses.

Another advantage of specialization is that one of the types can have different relationships as the other. In the example above, only the hourly payed employees can belong to a trade union, visualised by the diamond-shape 'BELONGS_TO'

## Applied to your question

You **could** in this case make a superclass of emails, and subclasses for emails with checkouts and emails without checkouts. These subclasses can than have additional attributes and the emails with checkouts can than relate to the checkouts table (as in the image).

So, as I said, you could do that, but in this case I think (as baao already said) it is not really necessary. The concept of specialization may be applied when the database expands, your system seems not in need of such specific design concepts for now. (specialization is usually used in database systems with more complex relations as in the image). This post provided some additional background on the general concept.

Hope this helps.

(image from [here](http://www.cs.montana.edu/%7Ehalla/csci440/n8/n8.html), these and other concepts are also explained on this webpage)

Comment: Very nice example, this does well to answer my question. Thanks!